# Userform opening in second place after running code

Tags: excel, vba, focus, vlookup

I've been going crazy with an issue in my code. I have this userform and it performs lots of vlookups into my worksheet that is hidden behind, and then populates many textboxes with the data found.
The problem is that if the user has more than one worksheet open besides my userform worksheet, this extra worksheet window gets in front of my userform so the user has to click again on the userform window to "reactivate" the focus.
My code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks("IPS TOOL 2021 REV3.xlsm")
    wb.Windows(1).Visible = True

    'Insert concatenated values through vlookup
    Sheets("GRAPHS").Range("A3") = ModelCombo.Value
    Sheets("GRAPHS").Range("B3") = yearcombo.Value

    'VLookups
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Worksheets("GRAPHS").Range("B:G")

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    TextBox2.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("Issue IDL", myRange, 3, False)
    TextBox3.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("Issue IDL", myRange, 4, False)
    TextBox10.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("Issue IDL", myRange, 6, False)
    TextBox4.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("N/E", myRange, 3, False)
    TextBox5.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("N/E", myRange, 4, False)
    TextBox11.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("N/E", myRange, 6, False)
    TextBox16.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("Disclosure List", myRange, 3, False)
    TextBox15.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("Disclosure List", myRange, 4, False)
    TextBox14.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("Disclosure List", myRange, 6, False)
    TextBox6.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("SAP Master Data Registration", myRange, 3, False)
    TextBox7.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("SAP Master Data Registration", myRange, 4, False)
    TextBox12.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("SAP Master Data Registration", myRange, 6, False)
    TextBox8.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("NCM", myRange, 4, False)
    TextBox9.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("NCM", myRange, 3, False)
    TextBox13.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("NCM", myRange, 6, False)
    TextBox18.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("Delay Comments", myRange, 3, False)
    TextBox17.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("Delayed Reason", myRange, 3, False)

    If Workbooks.Count > 1 Then
        wb.Windows(1).Visible = False
    Else
        wb.Windows(1).Visible = False
        Application.Visible = False
    End If

    Exit Sub

    spec_form.Show vbModeless

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox ("Please check Model and/or Year")
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try `spec_form.Show vbModal`? So the user is forced to use the form first, the Excel gets blocked as long as the userform is there.

Comment: Hi PeH, when the userform opens, it appears in first place but as soon as i run the code w/ the vlookups the other worksheets gets in front of the userform window, even using vbModal function

Comment: Hard to tell what's going on. Try to go through your code step by step using F8 to see which line of code exactly makes this behavior.